# Method from assembly 'Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy' does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, nuget, ninject

I'm getting this runtime error:

> Method 'CaptureProceedInfo' in type 'Ninject.Extensions.Interception.ProxyFactory.ObjectMethodsInvocation' from assembly 'Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy, Version=3.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' does not have an implementation.

Searching for that error brought me to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9988204). However, `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy` is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred when I updated the `Moq` NuGet package.

As of the time of posting, the latest version of `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy` is 3.3.3.

When I upgraded `Moq` to the latest version, it also upgraded `Castle.Core` to the latest version (4.4.0).

**The problem is, `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy` 3.3.3 only supports up to `Castle.Core` 4.3.1, not 4.4.0!**

Therefore, to solve, I needed to downgrade `Castle.Core` to 4.3.1, (which in turn downgraded `Moq` to 4.10.1).

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Can confirm that downgrading Moq to 4.10.1 works.